# Error while calling a phone number from iPhone app

Tags: iphone

I am using following code to make a phone call from my iPhone app:

```
NSURL *myPhone1 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"14165551212"];
[myPhone1 scheme:@"tel://"];
NSURLRequest *myPhoneReq = [[NSURLRequest alloc ] requestWithURL:myPhone1];
NSURLConnection *myCon = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:myPhoneReq delegate:self];
```

but getting following error:
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSURL scheme:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a10ba0

Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
                    openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel: 14165551212"]];
```

will not work in simulator

Comment: What Aaron says. NSURL does not have a `scheme:` method. It does have a `scheme` method (without a parameter). http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/scheme

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://14165551212"]]
```

That might fix your problem, however it won't work in the iPhone simulator.

Comment: I tried it, no error but I am not able to see any call happening on simulator the way you can see on Android simulator? Does it behave differently? No change on simulator?